# How Can I Make generic Service Provider calls in C#?

Tags: c#, web-services, generics, provider

Imagine I Have a Provider that provides me with a number of methods I can call remotely.

```
MyProviderManager.Provider.CallMyFunction(int x, int y, int z);
```

I Have a class that is used by several ways that specific variables are created in another classes that extends it.

For Example

```
[DataContract, Serializable]
public class InfoStatusServices
{
        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public char TypeService { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string IdUser { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public bool ResultStatus { get; set; } 
}
```

And One extending it

```
[DataContract, Serializable]
public class InfoStatusServicesXPTO : InfoStatusServices
{
    [DataMember]
    public decimal? Balance { get; set; }
}
```

My question is, assuming there are a couple of different types of methods that use the class `InfoStatusServices`

```
MyProviderManager.Provider.CallMyFunctionDark(InfoStatusServices info);
MyProviderManager.Provider.CallMyFunctionBlue(InfoStatusServices info);
```

Is there a proper way where I Can make a generic method for calling these instead of creating methods for all colours?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand, but the obvious way is to add another parameter for color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Color enumeration:

```
public enum Color
{
      None = 0, Black = 1, ...
}
```

and then you can use this argument as second parameter. So methods with same signature depending on colors can be epxressed as single method:

```
.CallMyFunction(InfoStatusServices info, Color color)
```

So calling this method for black color will like this:

```
.CallMyFunction(info, Color.Black)
```